# Control.Concurrent.Async.race and runInteractiveProcess

Tags: haskell

I'm using the `race` function from the `async` package, exported by `Control.Concurrent.Async`.

The subtasks I fire off using `race` themselves invoke `runInteractiveProcess` to run (non-Haskell) executables. The idea is to run different external programs and take the result of the first one to finish. In a sense, Haskell "orchestrates" a bunch of external programs.

What I'm observing is that while `race` works correctly by killing the Haskell level "slower" thread; the sub-processes spawned from the slow thread itself continue to run.

I suspect expecting `race` to kill processes spawned this way is a bit unrealistic, as they probably become zombies and get inherited by init. For my purposes however, keeping the external processes running defeats the whole purpose of using `race` in the first place.

Is there an alternative way of using `race` so the subprocesses created this way get killed as well? While I don't have a use case yet, it'd be best if the entire chain of processes created from the `race`d tasks get killed; as one can imagine those external programs themselves creating a bunch of processes as well.

Comment: I think there is no standard library function which does this, but on the other hand, you can code your own variant `asyncAndKill`.

Comment: Since `race` cancels a slower thread using an asynchronous exception, you can catch `ThreadKilled` by yourself and kill the process using `terminateProcess`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you could use a combination of [onException](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v%3aonException) and [terminateProcess](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v%3aterminateProcess).

My [process-streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming) library (which contains helper functions built on top of [process](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process) and [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes)) already does this. Asynchronous exceptions trigger the termination of the external process.

For example, the following code does not create file `toolate.txt`.

```
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as B
import System.Process.Streaming
import Control.Concurrent.Async

main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    result <-  race (runProgram prog1) (runProgram prog2)
    putStrLn $ show $ result
  where
    -- collecting stdout and stderr as bytestrings
    runProgram = simpleSafeExecute $ pipeoe $ 
                       separated (surely B.toLazyM) (surely B.toLazyM)
    prog1 = shell "{ echo aaa ; sleep 2 ; }"
    prog2 = shell "{ echo bbb ; sleep 7 ; touch toolate.txt ; }"
```

The result is:

```
Left (Right ("aaa\n",""))
```

Comment: `onException` and `terminateProcess` did indeed do the job. Thanks. 

If I knew about `process-streaming` library before, I would've used it for simplicity too!